# geom_jitter and stat_compare_means not working - is there a connection?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to make a simple boxplot + jitter with different groups that are facet wrapped. This worked perfectly fine yesterday and now it doesn't anymore. I have been digging through the forums but nothing seemed similar to my problem. I am at a complete loss what has changed for this to not work anymore.

This is the plot I am currently getting:
[image]

- the warning message:
  1: Computation failed in stat_signif():
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

What I want is p values for each comparison and obviously the jitter points not clustered but for each bar. I assume there is a connection between the failure of stat_signif() and the jitter issue.

My data is as follows:

```
> dput(test[sample(1:nrow(test), 30, replace=FALSE), ])
structure(list(Station_neat = c("003_DCM", "009_SA", "009_SA", 
"035_SA", "013_SA", "015_SA", "098_DCM", "027_DCM", "035_SA", 
"069_DCM", "073_SA", "045_DCM", "007_DCM", "009_DCM", "019_DCM", 
"049_DCM", "103_DCM", "009_SA", "065_SA", "047_DCM", "021_SA", 
"063_DCM", "049_SA", "051_DCM", "027_DCM", "007_DCM", "001_SA", 
"071_SA", "067_SA", "067_SA"), Trophy = c("Phototrophic", "Photo_Heterotrophic", 
"Unknown", "Phototrophic", "Heterotrophic", "Unknown", "Unknown", 
"Unknown", "Unknown", "Photo_Heterotrophic", "Phototrophic", 
"Heterotrophic", "Phototrophic", "Phototrophic", "Phototrophic", 
"Photo_Heterotrophic", "Unknown", "Heterotrophic", "Photo_Heterotrophic", 
"Unknown", "Phototrophic", "Heterotrophic", "Photo_Heterotrophic", 
"Unknown", "Phototrophic", "Unknown", "Heterotrophic", "Heterotrophic", 
"Photo_Heterotrophic", "Heterotrophic"), Zone = c("Oligotrophic", 
"Oligotrophic", "Oligotrophic", "Temperate", "Oligotrophic", 
"Oligotrophic", "Temperate", "Temperate", "Temperate", "Polar", 
"Polar", "Temperate", "Oligotrophic", "Oligotrophic", "Oligotrophic", 
"Temperate", "Temperate", "Oligotrophic", "Polar", "Temperate", 
"Oligotrophic", "Polar", "Temperate", "Temperate", "Temperate", 
"Oligotrophic", "Oligotrophic", "Polar", "Polar", "Polar"), Lat = c(-30.9975, 
-34.00016667, -34.00016667, -46.998, -36.00083333, -36.9985, 
-44.865, -42.99633333, -46.998, -58.00066667, -56.67116667, -53.00033333, 
-32.99816667, -34.00016667, -38.99833333, -51.67116667, -43.18316667, 
-34.00016667, -59.33383333, -52.335, -39.999, -59.99833333, -51.67116667, 
-51.00016667, -42.99633333, -32.99816667, -29.997, -57.33483333, 
-58.66866667, -58.66866667), x = c(0.203081382864505, 0.565058479532164, 
0.151969836872884, 0.403331082601846, 0.256978619577354, 0.384393951024795, 
0.0752896823196762, 0.0462908011869436, 0.0582039162727887, 0.237218270061831, 
0.424948270765593, 0.282785885109083, 0.238459319099827, 0.193018092493741, 
0.114429357167411, 0.281383721453989, 0.202223251505327, 0.217643890427824, 
0.412883700821444, 0.0529888650126978, 0.0987085906793936, 0.159411260805233, 
0.30349843140983, 0.0514790242929117, 0.0766002543450615, 0.128534333525678, 
0.231287858835923, 0.125564198597906, 0.408113870800438, 0.0713421310436236
)), row.names = c(261L, 236L, 240L, 102L, 218L, 216L, 127L, 167L, 
104L, 27L, 46L, 49L, 245L, 237L, 197L, 67L, 159L, 234L, 12L, 
63L, 190L, 1L, 68L, 79L, 165L, 247L, 266L, 34L, 20L, 18L), class = "data.frame")
```

My code to produce the figure (simplified) is:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

my_comparisons_Zone <- list( c("Oligotrophic", "Temperate"), c("Oligotrophic", "Polar"),c("Polar", "Temperate") )

ggplot(test, aes(x = Trophy, y = x, fill=Zone)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape  = NA, alpha=0.95) +
  geom_jitter(colour = "grey40", alpha=0.4, height = 0, width = .1) +
  facet_wrap(~ Trophy, scales = "free", nrow =2)+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons_Zone, label="p.signif", hide.ns=FALSE, col="blue", size=3, angle=90, method="wilcox.test")
```

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Could you perhaps add some more of your data frame, and also show us how you created the object `my_comparisons_Zone`?. The obvious thing from looking at your code is that the boxplots are grouped according to `Zone`, since you have specified that as their fill color, but there is no heritable grouping variable for `geom_jitter`. Does adding `group = Zone` in the `aes` of the `ggplot` line fix things?

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron, I added some more data & comparison. Hopefully it is reproducible now. Adding ````group=Zone```` in the ggplot line does not fix things unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparisons in stat_compare_means should be across x axis categories, not the groupings within each x value. Since you are already faceting according to `Trophy`, all you need to do is switch your `x` aesthetic to `Zone`:

```r
ggplot(test, aes(x = Zone, y = x, fill = Zone)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape  = NA, alpha = 0.95) +
  geom_jitter(colour = "grey40", alpha = 0.4, height = 0, width = .1) +
  facet_wrap(~ Trophy, scales = "free", nrow = 2)+
  stat_compare_means(comparisons = my_comparisons_Zone, 
                     label = "p.signif", hide.ns = FALSE, col = "blue", 
                     size = 3, angle = 90, method = "wilcox.test") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('#efb82d', '#31406e', '#8f70d0')) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much. I can't believe I spent two hours trying to resolve such a silly mistake. Maybe I should just start my weekend early...